# Multilingual website, translations stored in a local.php file or in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question! I want to create my website with multilingual content, but i have a doubt about which is the right way to do this.

**Option 1**: Create a .php file called for example lang.en.php (where there is an array of all the strings I use on the page) and include it in the header.php file, so that to add a new language i only have to create new files like lang.es.php

**Option 2**: Store the strings in a database table and take them with a query.

Now my question is this: when i will upload the website on a real server, which one is the faster method? which one slows down less?

Comment: Native PHP strings are marginally faster, but it's a pain to have a programmer rather then a translator having to add those. Some options include just using [`gettext`](http://www.php.net/gettext), or perhaps storing & updating in a database, but generating the php file with `var_export`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an option 3 use [mo/po files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) which are specialized for the task and also kinda nicely handle singulars / plurals for you.

However being sanely able to edit those files you would need to provide a GUI. But that should also be the case when you are using the array in a php file approach.

It's pretty hard to tell which way is the way ™ so I think I might close your question as too subjective.

When you are going for the database approach I would personally have a way to export the texts to either a po file or a array in a php file to prevent having to query the database for those mostly static texts.

To answer you question po files might be faster, however with opcache it might be pretty close to eachother. If you really want to know it the best thing you can do is do some tests with either approach because I just simply pulled the speed of po vs static array in a file out of my arse :-)

P.S. when you are benchmarking both methods also please keep in mind that whichever method you are going to choose performance is most likely not going to be the bottleneck so choosing one or another for performance is probably a bullshit reason.